# Поиск гласных в предложении

Tags: c++

Есть задача : **Вам даны несколько строчек текста - и для каждой из них требуется подсчитать количество гласных (т.е. букв a, o, u, i, e, y). Входные данные - в первой строке указано количество строк подлежащих обработке.
Дальше следуют сами строки, состоящие только из маленьких английских (латинских) букв и пробелов.
Ответ должен содержать количество гласных для каждой строки.**

Пример:

входные данные:

4
abracadabra

pear tree
o a kak ushakov lil vo kashu kakao

my pyx

ответ:
5 4 13 2

Написал код, немного рабочий, он может посчитать только количество гласных первой строки, а дальше не хочет, в чем проблема?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    char words[6] = { 'a','o','u','i','e','y' };
    string phrase;
    int count = 0;
    int n;
    cin >> n;

    getline(cin, phrase);


    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < phrase.length(); j++) {
            if (tolower(phrase[j]) == words[i]) count++;
        }
    }
    cout << count << " ";
}
```

Comment: Проблемы в том, что последующие строки вы не читаете и не обрабатываете...

Comment: А как? Мне создать массив phrase и передать туда значения через for? @Harry

Comment: В подобных случаях лучше сделать символьный массив из 256 символов, в которм элементы, индексируемые гласными будут равны 1, а все остальные нулю. Далее используете каждый символ из читаемых в цикле n строк в качестве индекса.

Comment: Да не нужен тебе массив, просто в цикл оберни.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно после `cin` нужно использовать `cin.ignore()`. Предлагаю cвой вариант:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n;

    cout << "Input number of lines: ";
    cin >> n;
    cin.ignore();

    char letters[256] = {0};

    letters['a'] = 1;
    letters['o'] = 1;
    letters['u'] = 1;
    letters['i'] = 1;
    letters['e'] = 1;
    letters['y'] = 1;

    vector<int> numbers;
    string phrase;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int count = 0;
        getline(std::cin, phrase);
        for (char c: phrase) {
            count += letters[c];
        }
        numbers.push_back(count);
    }

    for (int num: numbers) {
        cout << num << " ";
    }

    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: map тут, это из пушки по воробьям (пустая трата ресурсов). В подобных случаях лучше сделать символьный массив из 256 символов, в которм элементы, индексируемые гласными будут равны 1, а все остальные нулю.

Comment: @avp, полностью с вами согласен. Убрал.

Comment: да, работает, но мне всегда выводит сначала 0 из за чего приходится увеличить в ручную n на единицу, чтобы последняя строка не терялась. И какое то сложное решение получилось для начальных задач, как по мне. Но все равно спасибо @TigerTV.ru

Comment: @ADOLFABOOOBA, в смысле ноль сначала выводит? Какие данные вы вводите? Решение простое, в чем сложность?

Comment: @TigerTV.ru https://prnt.sc/13uek6r . Ввожу значения которые указывал после задачи. Не понимаю зачем нужен cin.ignore() , почему записан так массив, зачем вектор и в цикле (char c: phrase) что это за "c:"? Обычно мне хватало самых азов для решения задач

Comment: Проверьте [здесь](http://cpp.sh/5rohcw). У меня  [getline после cin не работал](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6649852/9210255) без cin.ignore(). Массив можно записать и по другому, не используя вектор - мне так удобнее, я написал как удобнее. `c` в [цикле это содержимое одного элемента из `phrase`](https://evileg.com/ru/post/256/). Привыкайте, что вам нужно будет знать не только азы и постоянно учиться новому.

Answer (score 1):

```
cin >> n;  

for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
    getline(cin, phrase);

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < phrase.length(); j++) {
            if (tolower(phrase[j]) == words[i]) count++;
        }
    }
    cout << count << " ";
}
```